# How do I keep my Login.aspx page's ReturnUrl parameter from overriding my ASP.NET Login control's DestinationPageUrl property?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm using the [ASP.NET Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) and [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) for membership/credentials for an ASP.NET web application.  I've got pages such as *PasswordRecovery.aspx* that are accessable to only Anonymous users.  When I click my login link from such a page, the login page has a *ReturnUrl* parameter in the address bar:

> http://www.example.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=PasswordRecovery.aspx

And then after a successful login, users are returned to the *PasswordRecovery.aspx* page specified in the *ReturnUrl* parameter to which they no longer have access.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer on [Velocity Reviews](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t367373-remove-quotreturnurlquot-from-url.html).  I handled the LoggedIn event to force a redirection to the DestinationPageUrl page.

```VB
Public Partial Class Login
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Login1_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, _  
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggedIn
        'overrides ReturnUrl page parameter
        Response.Redirect(Login1.DestinationPageUrl)
    End Sub

End Class
```